# Show geometry on a web map

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

Is there a simple webpage that I can paste a `geometry` field from `POSTGIS` (OSM data - sRID 900913) and it will show on the map?

Something like this http://www.darrinward.com/lat-long/ but with `geometry` data

I know there are a toon of apps that will do this, but this is just for quick checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure PostGIS geometry (EWKB) I guess not, but it you transform it to plain WKT with [ST_AsText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html), [this](http://www.samuelbosch.com/p/geometry-visualizer.html) or [this](http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html) should work.

I wouldn't be suprised if these struggle with geometries with lots of vertices though, so your mileage may vary.